# How do I send ALT + SPACE key using sendkey method?

Tags: c#, windows

I am implementing a desktop application in which I want to send an `ALT+SPACE` key combination but I can't find any way to do this.

I am implementing this for automatic processing the below tasks:

1. enter tracert command in command prompt
2. copy the result
3. paster the result in the notepad

Can anyone help me with this..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("% ");
```

**Edit**
Using `SendKeys` is a little 'hacky'. Instead I'd suggest using the Process class, something like below

```
public string GetTracert(string ip)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "tracert";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "123.123.123.123";
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();

    return p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Yes...this is working fine for other software but I need to implement this for Command prompt that is not working

Comment: No..this is the basic thing I want to do continuously and then I need big processing on those output so I need to do this..

Comment: Is there a way to copy and paste from cmd window..?

Answer (score 0):

Just Check out

> <strike>%{SPACE}</strike>

`SendKeys.Send("% ");` // {SPACE} is not valid, so use the regular " "

This should emulate the ALT + Space key press

Comment: Keyword "SPACE" is not valid.